# Error must declare the scalar variable @p3where, en JAVA, al intentar actualizar datos de la BD mendiante un boton

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hola a todos espero me puedan apoyar, me inicio en esto de JAVA y hacer conexiones con SQL y estoy de a poco con ejemplos aprendiendo, espero me puedan ayudar

Les explico estoy haciendo practicas y empece con una agenda, la cual todo iba funcionando bien hasta que me tope con el botón "ACTUALIZAR", que me bota un error y no se exactamente donde esta el error
el código el botón es el siguiente.

```
    JButton btnActualizar = new JButton("Actualizar");
        btnActualizar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


try {

                    String ActualizarSQL = "UPDATE contactos SET Nombre=?, Direccion=?, Telefono=?, Email=?"
                            + "WHERE ID=?";
                     int selectfila = table.getSelectedRow();
                     String dato = (String)table.getValueAt(selectfila,0);

                    PreparedStatement ps = agen.prepareStatement(ActualizarSQL);

                    ps.setString(1, txtNombre.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, txtDireccion.getText());
                    ps.setString(3, txtTelefono.getText());
                    ps.setString(4, txtEmail.getText());
                    ps.setString(5, dato);  


        // Se crea una variable que va almacenar un numero, EL CUAL SERA UN INDICADOR SI LOS DATOS SE AGREGARON O NO            
                    int n = ps.executeUpdate();
                    if(n>0) {
                        LlenarTabla();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos Guardados Correctamente");
                }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: "+e.getMessage());
                }



            }
        });
```

De la misma forma en SQL tengo la BD creada y los 5 campos estas correctos tanto Nombre, Direccion, Telefono, Email e ID, tal cual están respetando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Lo que digo en el codigo es que en la variable "dato", se guardo el "valor" del campo ID, y luego este sea reemplazado en en el QUERY ,. en WHERE=?  asi de esta forma se le hace el UPDATE a los campos relacionados a ese ID.

EL PROBLEMA ES QUE ME BOTA EL SIGUIENTE ERROR AL QUERER GUARDAR

"error must declare the scalar variable @p3where" Y el gran detalle es que no tengo ninguna variable llamada @p3Where, por lo que no encuentro el error en todo el codigo.

COMO dato adicional, la accion nuevo y guardar me funcionan sin mayor problemas

```
JButton btnGuardar = new JButton("Guardar");
        btnGuardar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                try {


                    String DatosSQL = ("INSERT INTO contactos VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");



                    PreparedStatement ps = agen.prepareStatement(DatosSQL);
                    ps.setString(1, txtId.getText());                   
                    ps.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());
                    ps.setString(3, txtDireccion.getText());
                    ps.setString(4, txtTelefono.getText());
                    ps.setString(5, txtEmail.getText());



                    int n = ps.executeUpdate();
                    if(n>0) {
                        LlenarTabla();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos Guardados Correctamente");
                }



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error: "+e.getMessage());
                }



            }
        });
        btnGuardar.setBounds(120, 438, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnGuardar);
```

Espero puedan apoyarme, gracias.

Comment: Me parece que al insertar un valor se ejecuta un trigger y el SP necesita esa variable: @p3where

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu código el error me parece ser el siguiente...

```
String ActualizarSQL = "UPDATE contactos SET Nombre=?, Direccion=?, Telefono=?, Email=?"
                        + "WHERE ID=?";
```

es exactamente lo mismo que

```
String ActualizarSQL = "UPDATE contactos SET Nombre=?, Direccion=?, Telefono=?, Email=?WHERE ID=?";
```

como verás no hay espacio antes del `WHERE` y por ello debería de fallar.

Comment: acabo de verlo y bueno acabo de borrar ese espacio, pero igual me sigue apareciendo el error

String ActualizarSQL = "UPDATE contactos SET Nombre=?, Direccion=?, Telefono=?, Email=?"+"WHERE ID=?";

Comment: te sigue saliendo `error must declare the scalar variable @p3where`?